# Pins in IC74138

Tags: integrated-circuit, decoder

IC74138(a 3:8 decoder) has 3 enable pins G1, G2A and G2B.

Why are there 3 enable pins and what is the reason for that nomenclature?

Comment: Depends on the manufacturer, Motorola used E1, E2, E3

Comment: But why 3 when one would suffice? Or at least, would one enable pin be sufficient?

Comment: One may be sufficient for you ...but at the time that SSI and MSI devices were being used heavily it may have been a worthy feature. It would allow more address definition or clocking capability. Only having one enable signal would have allowed it to fit in a 14 pin package, so there must have been a commercial implication that drove using two extra pins.

Comment: [First page of the datasheet explains it.](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?genericPartNumber=sn54ls138&fileType=pdf). Maybe someone would like to make an answer of it. Got to run now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The datasheet for the 74138](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?genericPartNumber=sn54ls138&fileType=pdf) explicitly says that the three enable inputs were a design decision that is intended to make it easy to use multiple 74138 chips together to for a one out of 24 or one out of 32 decoder.

Extract from the Datasheet:

[image]

With the multiple enables that have different active states (inverted vs. non-inverted,) you can build a one of 24 decoder with no additional inverters in the circuit - saved you a chip full of inverters back in day when they didn't come in SMD form with a single inverter in the package.

[This answer from last year](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/236897/47070) shows how the 74138 can be used to build a 1 out of 24 decoder.  That example does use additional inverters, but that is because the circuit is doing a bit more than just decoding the inputs - it appears to be using the third enable as a value ot be passed to the outputs.  It selects one output, and passes the value at Data-In to that ouput.  Were it not for that, there would be no need of the additional inverters, and the 74138s would work together as a 24 output decoder.

---

Circuit from the linked answer:

[image]

Comment: "explicitly says that the three enable inputs were a design decision that is intended to make it easy to use multiple 74138 chips together to form a one out of 24 or one out of 32 decoder." that's a bit of a stretch of what it actually says. Especially when you removed the period from between two sentences.

Answer (score 1):

[From this question...](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/343412/how-does-active-high-decoder-workd/343425#343425)

Some devices do indeed have multiple enables, some have a mix of high and low. This is partly done to make the device more convenient for use and, in some cases I am fairly sure, were added to use up all the pins on the package.

It is common to use them to divide up the functionality when using them for address decoding.

With multiple enables you can double up deviced to have a read decode and a write decode. In which case one would have the /E line attached to whatever /Write_Enable line comes from the micro, while the other would have the active high E pin connected to /Write Enable.

For a decoder, you can also use them as additional address lines, or to clock, synchronize, the output.